# CBPeripheral name not updating

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth device that is able to update it's advertised name. I then use this code to read the new name in my app:

```
NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
```

When I do so, the variable `localName` then contains the updated name. However when this function gets called:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

`peripheral.name` retains the old name. I tried several things to get it to grab the new name (e.g. I tried resetting the Bluetooth device, resetting my iPad, uninstall/reinstalling my app) but none of these things worked.  After leaving it alone for a couple hours I came back and `peripheral.name` finally updated to reflect the value in `localName`.

I thought maybe there was a way for the Bluetooth device to advertise one name and then report as another, but I found a scenario that has convinced me the problem is in the iOS app. The Bluetooth device was advertising as "Name A". I discovered the device with my iPod and my iPad. Both devices saw "Name A". I updated the device's name to "Name B". I discovered the device with my iPod and it still reported the device as "Name A".  After some time it finally updated to "Name B". I changed the device's name to "Name C". The iPod is reporting "Name B" and the iPad is still reporting "Name A".

Has anyone seen this problem? Is there a way to refresh the `CBPeripheral.name` value?

I just noticed that the iPad started reporting "Name C" after I connected to the device for the first time. Is there a way to update the name before connecting to it?

Comment: Hi Ryan, how to update it's name? Is there any open source sample you have used for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the Manufacturer Data in CBAdvertisement.DataLocalName in the AdvertisementData property when you discover a device.

Comment: You mean CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey, but that's not the Manufacturer Data, it's the local name (as the key suggests). And this is exactly what the OP says they're doing. This is not an answer to the question of how to be notified when it changes.